# Check if string is balanced with brackets

Tags: python, string, debugging, recursion

I have to write Python supplementary function:

```
def find(searched, open)
```

for function which recursively checks if the input string has balanced brackets:

```
def balanced (text):
    #....
    return find(text, None)[1]
```

I can't use stack. I have to include option, when input string is empty, when the bracket is opening and closing (and a small hint, that not for every closing bracket we should react the same) and include reaction to character other than brackets.
The supplementary function has to return unprocessed text and previous outcome.

I have code, which sadly doesn't work for every example I found:

```
PAIRS = {'(' : ')', '[' : ']'}

def balanced(text):
    #supp. f.
    def find(searched, open):         
        if not searched:
            return "", open is None
        rest, val = find(searched[1:], searched[0])
        if searched[0] in PAIRS.keys():
            return find(rest, open)
        elif searched[0] in PAIRS.values():
            if val is False:
                return rest, False
            elif open is not None and searched[0] == PAIRS [open]:
                return searched[1:], True
        else:
            return find(searched[1:], open)    
    return find(text, None)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("No string: ")
    print(balanced(""))
    print("########################")
    print("-----abc: ")
    print(balanced("abc"))
    print("########################")
    print("-----(a): ")
    print(balanced("(a)"))
    print("########################")
    print("-----)a(: ")
    print(balanced(")a("))
    print("########################")
    print("-----((a): ")
    print(balanced("((a)"))
    print("########################")
    print("-----((a(: ")
    print(balanced("((a("))
    print("########################")
    print("-----))a): ")
    print(balanced("))a)"))
    print("########################")
    print("-----()(a): ")
    print(balanced("()(a)"))
    print("########################")
    print("-----a(a): ")
    print(balanced("a(a)"))
```

In tests, wrong answers are returned in

```
((a)
```

and

```
((a(
```

I tried to use **pdb** and online visualization debugger from *pythontutor.com*, but I cannot wrap the recursion there as a whole... The tricky situation there is that it is Parson's puzzle too and I can't just write it much differently.

Where I went wrong?

Comment: Write a regex to find occurrences of any of `()[]` and increment a counter for each opening bracket, decrement for each closing. If (1) the counter is never negative and (2) the final counter value is 0 the brackets are balanced. Maybe you need different counters for `()` and `[]`.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I know this way of solving this, at the end I include the additional information, that it is Parson's puzzle - so I have to juggle only with the while lines and indents, I cannot edit code... I used nearly all of them, except `return searched[1:], False `

Answer (score 0):

This gets the result you're looking for:

**Code**

```
CASES = ["", 'abc', '(a)', ')a(', '((a)', '((a(', '))a)', '()(a)', 'a(a)' ]

left_pairs  = ['(','[']
right_pairs = [')',']']

def balanced(case):
    count = 0
    for char in left_pairs:
        count += case.count(char)
    for char in right_pairs:
        count -= case.count(char)

    if count == 0 or count % 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False

for case in CASES:
    print(str(balanced(case)) + "  " + case)
```

**Returns**

```
True  
True  abc
True  (a)
True  )a(
False  ((a)
False  ((a(
False  ))a)
True  ()(a)
True  a(a)
```

Comment: I know this way of solving this with counting numbers of left and right brackets.
At the end I include the additional information, that it is Parson's puzzle - so I have to juggle only with the lines and indents,
 I cannot edit code... I used nearly all of them, except `return searched[1:], False `
It is the recursion which is hardest there for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found correct answer with help of my friends, the order of the commands was wrong and some intents were not in the correct place too.

I find this code hard to read and too complex to use, though maybe it was the challenge there. 
The version with stack is more universal for me.

There is working version for the future users:

```
PAIRS = {'(' : ')', '[' : ']'}

def balanced(text):
#supp. f.
def find(searched, open):         
    if not searched:
        return "", open is None
    if searched[0] in PAIRS.keys():
        rest, val = find(searched[1:], searched[0])
        if val is False:
            return rest, False
        return find(rest, open)  
    elif open is not None and searched[0] == PAIRS[open]:
        return searched[1:], True
    elif searched[0] in PAIRS.values():
        return searched[1:], False
    else:
        return find(searched[1:], open)
return find(text, None)
```